# Docker Postgresql wsl

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, wsl2

Существует конфиг `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./factory/init_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/factory_init_db.sh
      - ./shop/init_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/shop_init_db.sh
      - ./purchases_storage/init_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/purchases_init_db.sh
```

И т.к.

> Bear in mind as per the documentation, "scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty"

,то встал вопрос как очистить `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

И вот мне совершенно не понятно где искать эту самую директорию, ибо неизвестен механизм работы данного детища.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел достаточно костыльное решение.

В `/mnt` я нашел директорию `wsl`. У меня появились подозрения, что именно там хранятся данные.

Я убил докер на `Windows` и `sudo rm -rf /mnt/wsl/*`, после чего данные базы данных действительно исчезли.

Comment: Хотя в теории помогает даже простой перезапуск докера.

Comment: Некостыльное было бы удалить volume `docker volume rm database_data` (или `docker volume rm docker_database_data`)